# iptables rule doesn't work for port 80

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, http

My VM has set some rules for access to a web server and a SSH.
The server is running in the internal port 8080 en redirected using iptables to the port 80 with the command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

When i add the rule to DROP INPUT and afterwards the one for oppening the port

```
IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

it doesnt work.

I have the same setup on port 4422 for the SSH server and works perfectly but not in the http one.

IPTABLES --LIST:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4422
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere(this one is for the lo)
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prerouting takes place *before* INPUT, so you will need to ACCEPT from 8080, not 80.

```
IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```